# Other ways to define a turning point

Tags: word-choice

After a difficult childhood, the encounter with Rev. Charles, was a *turning point* in his life. 
What other expressions can be used to to define the concept of *turning point?*

Comment: The words *epiphany* and *watershed* come to mind but they have different nuances relating to the effect or outcome of the turning point.

Comment: ...was the one moment to change his life.

Comment: Among the many good suggestions so far, you might also consider transforming moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some words I would use...

1. crossroads
2. critical/decisive/defining moment
3. tipping point
4. Pivotal moment

Pivotal would be my favorite...

From http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/pivotal

Pivotal means important, but it has the sense of centrality and turning.

An election can be a pivotal moment in a nation's history if the direction the country takes depends on it.

Using it in your sentence..

After a difficult childhood, the encounter with Rev. Charles, was a ***pivotal moment*** in his life

Answer (score 1):

Consider "turning corner."

> After a difficult childhood, the encounter with Rev. Charles was a *turning corner* in his life.

**[corner](http://arizona.openrepository.com/arizona/handle/10150/191024):** a point at which significant change occurs -- often used in the phrase *turn the corner*.

**turn a corner:** make a dramatic change for the better in one's life.

[It's been a long road and the last year proved to be a turning corner in my life, where I finally have stability, know where I am going and where I am not.](http://fivemonthsinbarcelona.wordpress.com/2014/01/09/welcome-back/)

[The industrial revolution was a turning corner in the history of water management.](http://arizona.openrepository.com/arizona/handle/10150/191024)

Also, how about rephrasing?

> After a difficult childhood, the encounter with Rev. Charles helped him *turn a corner* in his life.
>
> After a difficult childhood, the encounter with Rev. Charles dramatically changed his life.
>
> After a difficult childhood, the encounter with Rev. Charles marked a dramatic shift in his life.
>
> After a difficult childhood, the encounter with Rev. Charles changed his life from the inside out.

Comment: Your other examples are good, but to my ear this is not a good use _a turning corner_.  In fact, I would generally reference _to turn the corner_, but not use _a turning corner_.  All corners turn, it's kind of in the definition.  I realize you quoted what appears to be a native AmE speaker, but this is not natural use of the phrase in AmE.  I have not heard this used in other versions of English, but may have overlooked it.

Comment: @mike Sure. The only thing is "turning corner" apparently is the expression that comes the closest to what "turning point" implies, i.e. a radical change/shift in the course of one's life. "Crossroads," "climax," and other "critical moment" style expressions don't share the same connotation to my ear.

Comment: Ok, I agree with you regarding the others.  I guess it goes back to what you said above, it's actually _turning the/a corner_ which requires restructuring of the sentence.  _Turning corner_ implies that this corner is different than others because it turns...it's odd.  It's all good, people would generally understand the intent.

Answer (score 1):

The word [climacteric](https://www.google.com.sg/search?q=define+climacteric&oq=define+climacteric) is defined as a turning point.

Answer (score 0):

Landmark is an option.
After a difficult childhood, the encounter with Rev. Charles was a landmark in his life.

Inflection point is also a viable option that isn't overused.

My personal favorite is juncture.

After a difficult childhood, the encounter with Rev. Charles was a juncture in his life.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inflection_point):

> an inflection point, point of inflection, flex, or inflection (inflexion) is a point on a curve at which the curve changes from being concave (concave downward) to convex (concave upward), or vice versa.

"*My life reached an **inflection point** when I finally woke, covered in vomit, with three empty bottles of Jägermeister lying on the floor, and a fourth, half full, still clenched in my outstretched fist. **Something** had to change.*"